# PLSQL function aggregate select loop

Tags: function, loops, select, plsql, aggregate

I am trying to create a function in PLSQL that does the following:

- Get a list of id's from my BD.
- Iterate over it in a loop and do a SELECT using one of its properties in a the WHERE.
- Aggregate all the loop iterations results in one single variable/whatever and return it as the result of the function. (concatenated string comma separated or anything would work)

what i got so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION loop(OUT str text)
RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE
    i text;
BEGIN
str := '';

FOR i IN
    SELECT id from public.factors
    LOOP
        str :=  str || ',' || #query - ex: select name from public.factors where factors.id = i # 
      -- Here i would like to do a select, return a single value from it and aggregate it to the existing value in str
    END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

PS: the logic of the example is a simplified version of what i need to do. so any simplification of its logic in a single query etc its not a valid solution to the original problem.

Comment: If you are using the same tables for your loop, then I don't think you need to go such length for it. You can just `SELECT id||', '|| name from public.factors `.  But your ex is just random, then it would be helpful if you changed the table name in your example...

Answer (score 1):

Here's simplest way I know:

```
SELECT LISTAGG (name, ',') FROM public.factors
```

The Oracle/PLSQL LISTAGG function concatenates values of the column for each GROUP based on the `order_by_clause`. But you can use it without `group by` and `order by` too.

If your cells values are more than 4000 characters, which is the max for varchar in oracle, and you are using something like `CLOB`, you can use this one instead, for larger strings:

```
SELECT XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (NOENTITYESCAPING e, name, ',').EXTRACT ('//text()') ORDER BY name).getclobval ()
FROM public.factors
```

But if you want to use loop, then here's something like your example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION loop(OUT str text)
RETURNS text AS
$func$
DECLARE
    v_name text;
BEGIN
str := '';

FOR i IN
    SELECT id from public.factors
    LOOP
    select name into v_name from public.factors where factors.id = i.id;
        str :=  str || ',' || v_name;
    END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: `LISTTAG` is really useful. But I have never heard or seen your 2nd solution, so can't say anything much about that